# Edit windows HOST file using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to copy content from another file into my windows host file.

I have tried running it as a administrator but it still does not work.

Any help or alternative methods to do this would be appreciated!

```
Filetocopy = File.read('assets/backup/copy_host')
File.open('C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts', 'w+') do |copy|
   copy.puts Filetocopy.to_s
end
```

The error I get is - `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

Comment: I don't think this is a Ruby problem, but instead a Windows permissions problem.

Comment: Can you start your ruby scrips as an admin?

Comment: Did not make a difference really (running as admin). I get the same error....

Comment: I'm not a Windows programmer, but I have seen permission problems that running as an admin does not work around.